# C setting a pointer to another pointer and freeing

Tags: c, pointers

Would p1 also be free'd if I called `free(ptr)`?

```
int* some_function(){
    int *p1 = malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
    int *p2 = p1;
    return p2;
}
int main(){
    int *ptr = some_function();
    free(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't free `p1` or `p2` themselves. What needs to be freed is the memory you allocated, i.e. the memory that `p1` and `p2` (and then `ptr`) _point to_.

Comment: Yes, Like it's name can tell, a `pointer` points to an `area of memory`, what you are freeing is never the pointer itself BUT the area pointed by the pointer, you can't "free" a pointer, you can free the memory it's pointing at.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you do

```
int *p1 = malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
```

you have something like

```
+----+     +---------------------------------+
| p1 | --> | Memory enough for 10 int values |
+----+     +---------------------------------+
```

Then when you do

```
int *p2 = p1;
```

you have something like

```
+----+
| p1 | --\
+----+    \     +---------------------------------+
           >--> | Memory enough for 10 int values |
+----+    /     +---------------------------------+
| p2 | --/
+----+
```

That is, you have two pointers pointing to the very same memory.

When you return `p2` you simply copy the pointer, much like what happens when you initialize `p2`, and inside the `main` function you have

```
int *ptr = some_function();
```

which leads to

```
+-----+     +---------------------------------+
| ptr | --> | Memory enough for 10 int values |
+-----+     +---------------------------------+
```

It's different variables, but their contents are all the same, and it is the pointer returned by the initial `malloc` call.

Comment: Nice work! One diagram is more than enough to explain it.

Comment: Great explanation, are you made this diagram by hand or there is a tool?

Comment: @andymcgregor I do it all by hand. :)

Answer (score 1):

`*p1` is just an address sized area, which if the system uses long as the address and long's are described with 8 bytes, pointer uses 8 bytes from the memory area. And if you set

```
*p2 = p1;
```

you are simply copying the integer value to another integer value, which will point to the same address.

**For example:**

```
int *p = malloc(3);
```

Just for visualization, if our heap memory starts at 0x0001, p will be reserved for holding the start address which is (0x0001) which points to our 3 byte reserved memory area.

```
int *p1 = p;
```

this p1 value will also point to that 3 byte memory area, which is described by 0x0001 address, so they will contain the same value.

**Total memory used:**  4 bytes for `p`, 4 bytes for `p1`, and 3 bytes for the memory that `p` and `p1` points.

```
*ptr = somefunction();
```

Then when you return that value to outside, `p` and `p1` will be freed, because of their scope, local variables. We return only 0x0001 which is our memory start address. The reserved memory is still reserved.

If you free `*ptr`, it will free the reserved memory (3 bytes at 0x0001 address) because it points to it.

And `*ptr` will still use some memory until the program exists.

Upvoted @some-programmer-dude's answer while I was writing this, because he has visualized that better than me.

Answer (score 0):

At the time that `some_function` returns, `p1` and `p2` have the same value, i.e. a pointer to a region of memory returned by `malloc`.  That value is then returned from the function with `return p2`.  There is no memory leak here because the value returned from `malloc` is returned from `some_function`.  The fact that this value happened to be stored in multiple local variables is irrelevant.

When `free(ptr)` is then called in `main`, the value of `ptr` is again the value returned from `malloc`, so the memory is correctly free'ed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

A pointer is a variable whose value is a memory address. You need to free that memory address (you actually free a block starting at that address - `free` will take care of that) and, in order to do that, you need to pass to `free` a pointer to it.

You can have multiple pointers to a memory location, and, since calling `free` with one of them frees that memory location, they will all now point to free'd memory (be careful with them).